# How are Java Nested Arrays implemented in memory?

Tags: java, memory

Consider a nested array in java. Does the top level of the array contain *references* to the inner arrays, or does the memory actually contain the inner arrays themselves?

If you need an illustration, assume I have access to a `reverse` method, which will reverse an array in place by doing multiple swaps. If I call `reverse` on the top-level of an M*N nested array, what will that method simply swap references around (an O(m) operation), or will it be swapping entire rows around (an O(m*n) operation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word *references*.  Arrays themselves are likely to be contiguous blocks, but it's unlikely that the Objects the elements refer to are.

This article sums it up nicely http://java.dzone.com/articles/what-does-java-array-look

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find the answer in most introductory Java book (although it may be not that obvious).

In Java, nested/multi-dimension array is not a continuous block. It is simply an array of "reference to array".